# need help placing JS code result/return inside div

Tags: html, raphael

I found this jsfiddle online that does exactly what I've been looking for... the problem is is that it creates the visual using pure JS. I wanted to put that inside a div so I could control it... Like defining exact placement, margins, adding opacity, etc...

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7jHPv/52/

Right now "I'm" placing the visual on the page through the JS code itself, wondering how I can "load it" inside that container div.

So, taking the example on the jsfiddle, instead of being at the position given by the code, make it follow the margins I attributed to the container div... by putting it inside the div.

I see this:

```
return {
   path: path
};
```

Can I change the return there to "add it" to the container div? Or something...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
var paper = new Raphael(100, 300, 0, 100, side);
```

make the definition

```
var paper = new Raphael("container", 100, side);
```

where container is the name of your div. From there you can control the div's location, margins/padding and whatever else

Comment: Did you try that on the jsfiddle I provided? I tried "container", "#container", container... none worked...

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/7jHPv/55/.  There is a slight problem of jsfiddle having a div named 'container'.
And you just beat me Peter :)

Comment: apologies, one too many arguments.  the assignment should look like `var paper = new Raphael("container", 100, side);`  I'll edit the answer